# Type error : you must pass a valid list of files to parse

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

[here  I got this error when adding the tailwind CSS.screenshot is attached herewith](https://github.com/charuka-dissanayaka/img/blob/main/sal2.PNG)

```
  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC8NS.png][1]
package.json file
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "buid:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css"
  },
```

when I creating react app here I got an error. for CSS I used tailwind CSS. I did several changes .but the error was the same. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Please try to properly elaborate the question and the issue. Also, Please consider adding code snippets and/or any reproducible environment.

Comment: @AniketKolekar screenshot is attached herewith. let me know how do I fix this?

Comment: @charukadissanayaka FYI, in the code you included, you have a typo on the `buid:css` line. It should probably be `build:css`. But without also knowing what command you inputed to generate the error, or what your desired result is, it will be hard to help...

Answer (score 6):

Hei, I have the same problem, the problem is simple because a folder like assets does not exist, make sure the part

```
src/assets/tailwind.css
```

is exist in

```
watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css
```

you can try to search part `src/assets/tailwind.css` in your directory folder

hope my answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

you have some syntax error try this instead

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cross verify the `package.json` file and `static` folder parent directory is same.
I was having the same issue and then realized my `package.json` file and `static` folder not belongs to same parent